# Is there a shortcut for summary information in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

If you mouse over a function or method, the following window appears.[image]

[image]

Is it possible to toggle a help window like this with a shortcut key?
I want to use this function using the keyboard, but I don't know how to set it up. If anyone knows, please let me know, thank you.

Comment: have you tried `Ctrl+Space` or `Ctrl+Shift+Space`

Comment: I use mac, press that key to change language, can you tell me the name of the binding?

Comment: `editor.action.triggerSuggest`, `toggleSuggestionDetails`, `editor.action.triggerParameterHints`